# Unable to set up sftp artifact storage for MLFlow

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sftp, mlflow

I want to set up a tracking MLFlow server with external metrics and artifact storage.
I have the following docker containers inside docker network: mlflow-server, postgres, sftp-mlflow and python-client.
I was able to set up postgres and connect it to the mlflow-server and the client:

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://postgres:<pass>@mlflow_db:5432/mlflow_db --default-artifact-root sftp://sftp:<pass>@sftp-mlflow:22 -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
```

However I cannot do anything about artifact storage. Tried the following sftp images

- https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp
- https://github.com/madnificent/root-sftp-docker

Also followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@gyani91/setup-mlflow-in-production-d72aecde7fef).
But still artifact storage doesn't work =(

On my client side I have

```py
import mlflow
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

remote_server_uri = "http://mlflow-server:8000" # set to your server URI
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(remote_server_uri)

# plotting
fig.savefig("test.png")

ARTIFACT_URI = "sftp://sftp:<pass>@sftp-mlflow:22"
EXPERIMENT_NAME = "test"
mlflow.create_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME, artifact_location=ARTIFACT_URI)
mlflow.set_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME)
with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.log_param("a", 1)
    mlflow.log_metric("b", 2)
    mlflow.log_artifact('test.png')
```

and when running this code I get:

```
2020/08/06 01:05:19 ERROR mlflow.utils.rest_utils: API request to http://mlflow-server:8000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/create failed with code 500 != 200, retrying up to 0 more times. API response body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/run.py", line 24, in <module>
    mlflow.create_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME, artifact_location=ARTIFACT_URI)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 357, in create_experiment
    return MlflowClient().create_experiment(name, artifact_location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 164, in create_experiment
    return self._tracking_client.create_experiment(name, artifact_location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 126, in create_experiment
    return self.store.create_experiment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 54, in create_experiment
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(CreateExperiment, req_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 32, in _call_endpoint
    return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 142, in call_endpoint
    response = http_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 86, in http_request
    raise MlflowException("API request to %s failed to return code 200 after %s tries" %
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://mlflow-server:8000/api/2.0/mlflow/experiments/create failed to return code 200 after 3 tries
```

I can connect to sftp storage from mlflow-server contaner and from python client using sftp:
`sftp -P 22 sftp@sftp-mlflow`

Comment: Also I'm able to manually log in and upload artifact to SFTP server using https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/0bfb3896b06fdfcc6edad572181d4b96911b91e4/mlflow/store/artifact/sftp_artifact_repo.py#L11

Answer (score 1):

In your mlflow-server you've already defined the default artifact store, so I assume it is not necessary to specify this on the client side. Have you tried `mlflow.create_experiment(EXPERIMENT_NAME)` already?

On another note: How did you specify the users on your sftp server (command arguments, environment variables or file)? The MLflow documentation suggests not to use user:pass, but instead...

> configure the client to be able to log in to the SFTP server without a password over SSH (e.g. public key, identity file in ssh_config, etc.)

https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#sftp-server